# hyperref package: why am I getting this TeX capacity exceeded fatal error?

Tags: latex, hyperref

I'm converting a document written for print distribution to one for electronic distribution by turning all of the URLs into hyperlinked URLs. Using the hyperref package and \url command. A single URL is giving me the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\font@name ->
             \OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 
l.4 .../\$FILE/Open\%20Meetings\%20Law\%20FAQ.pdf}
                                                  
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on FSGuide2022ElecProbMinEx.log.
```

I can't figure out why.

Here's a minimal example (with the offending URL) that gives this behavior.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{https://app.lla.state.la.us/llala.nsf/BAADB2991272084786257AB8006EE827/\$FILE/Open\%20Meetings\%20Law\%20FAQ.pdf} 
\end{document}
```

I'm probably making some silly mistake, but I can't for the life of me see what it is!

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome! I think this is better suited for tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, JoRa. I've been using TeX in some form for decades, but I'm a newb asking for help in online forums. I'll try over there.

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655078/36296

Comment: @close voter: please check the target site first before voting to migrate. It makes no sense to migrate this just to have two identical versions of the same post on one site.